# Is class member access through a pointer to data member considered a member access expression?

Tags: c++, templates, types, language-lawyer, c++20

One of the rules explaining how the `decltype` keyword works states that:
*If the argument is [...] an **unparenthesized class member access expression**, then `decltype` yields the type of the entity named by this expression.* (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)
However, consider the following example (pseudo-code for brevity):

```
struct X {
    int a;
};

X x;
int X::* ptr = &X::a;
std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(x.*ptr)>::value; //Evaluates to 1. The type is int&
std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(X().*ptr)>::value; //Evaluates to 1. The type is int&&
```

This implies that accessing a class member through a pointer to member is *not* a class member access expression. It's treated as if it was just a normal expression, for which the rule I quoted doesn't apply.
Therefore, my question is: how can I know what exactly counts as a class member access expression for the purpose of `decltype`? What source should I look into to find a precise definition?

Answer (score 2):

Class member access is defined in [[expr.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref).

It is:

> A postfix expression followed by a dot `.` or an arrow `->`, optionally followed by the keyword `template`, and then followed by an *id-expression*

`x.y` is class member access, `get().y` is class member access, `x.template y<int>()` is class member access, etc.

But neither `x.*ptr` nor `X().*ptr` are, because of the `*`. They are pointer-to-member operators, which are described in [[expr.mptr.oper]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mptr.oper). They also have different (lower) precedence from class member access: `x.*y.z` evaluates as `x.*(y.z)`.